# intersectionObserver is not working properly - intersection ratio seems abnormally low, CSS styles not applying correctly

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

My aim is to have the images appear and slide horizontally in to place as I scroll down.

I have 4 floated images translated off the document and with opacity:0. I have tried to apply an intersersectionObserver to each of the images, but when I log the intersection ratio, it is under 0.1 for most of the images, even when they are fully within the viewport (I didn't set a root).

I tried to deal with this by tweaking the root margin, but that seemed to make no difference. My .active CSS class does get triggered for all of the images when I scroll down, but I don't know why. Also, the transition I set to my CSS classes seems not to be working.

I suspect I made a mistake in my use of intersectionObserver, but after reading the documentation, I cannot see where I have gone wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="site-wrap">

    <h1>Slide in on Scroll</h1>

    <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariaturlores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
    <p>Adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum..</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore tempora rerum, est autem cupiditate, corporis a qui libero ipsum delectus quidem dolor at nulla, adipisci veniam in reiciendis aut asperiores omnis blanditiis quod quas laborum nam! Fuga ad tempora in aspernatur pariatur fugit quibusdam dolores sunt esse magni, ut, dignissimos.</p>

    <img src="http://unsplash.it/400/400" class= "slide-in">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, deserunt facilis et iste corrupti omnis tenetur est. Iste ut est dicta dolor itaque adipisci, dolorum minima, veritatis earum provident error molestias. Ratione magni illo sint vel velit ut excepturi consectetur suscipit, earum modi accusamus voluptatem nostrum, praesentium numquam, reiciendis voluptas sit id quisquam. Consequatur in quis reprehenderit modi perspiciatis necessitatibus saepe, quidem, suscipit iure natus dignissimos ipsam, eligendi deleniti accusantium, rerum quibusdam fugit perferendis et optio recusandae sed ratione. Culpa, dolorum reprehenderit harum ab voluptas fuga, nisi eligendi natus maiores illum quas quos et aperiam aut doloremque optio maxime fugiat doloribus. Eum dolorum expedita quam, nesciunt</p>

    <img src="http://unsplash.it/400/401" class="slide-in">

    <p> at provident praesentium atque quas rerum optio dignissimos repudiandae ullam illum quibusdam. Vel ad error quibusdam, illo ex totam placeat. Quos excepturi fuga, molestiae ea quisquam minus, ratione dicta consectetur officia omnis, doloribus voluptatibus? Veniam ipsum veritatis architecto, provident quas consequatur doloremque quam quidem earum expedita, ad delectus voluptatum, omnis praesentium nostrum qui aspernatur ea eaque adipisci et cumque ab? Ea voluptatum dolore itaque odio. Eius minima distinctio harum, officia ab nihil exercitationem. Tempora rem nemo nam temporibus molestias facilis minus ipsam quam doloribus consequatur debitis nesciunt tempore officiis aperiam quisquam, molestiae voluptates cum, fuga culpa. Distinctio accusamus quibusdam, tempore perspiciatis dolorum optio facere consequatur quidem ullam beatae architecto, ipsam sequi officiis dignissimos amet impedit natus necessitatibus tenetur repellendus dolor rem! Dicta dolorem, iure, facilis illo ex nihil ipsa amet officia, optio temporibus eum autem odit repellendus nisi. Possimus modi, corrupti error debitis doloribus dicta libero earum, sequi porro ut excepturi nostrum ea voluptatem nihil culpa? Ullam expedita eligendi obcaecati reiciendis velit provident omnis quas qui in corrupti est dolore facere ad hic, animi soluta assumenda consequuntur reprehenderit! Voluptate dolor nihil veniam laborum voluptas nisi pariatur sed optio accusantium quam consectetur, corrupti, sequi et consequuntur, excepturi doloremque. Tempore quis velit corporis neque fugit non sequi eaque rem hic. Facere, inventore, aspernatur. Accusantium modi atque, asperiores qui nobis soluta cumque suscipit excepturi possimus doloremque odit saepe perferendis temporibus molestiae nostrum voluptatum quis id sint quidem nesciunt culpa. Rerum labore dolor beatae blanditiis praesentium explicabo velit optio esse aperiam similique, voluptatem cum, maiores ipsa tempore. Reiciendis sed culpa atque inventore, nam ullam enim expedita consectetur id velit iusto alias vitae explicabo nemo neque odio reprehenderit soluta sint eaque. Aperiam, qui ut tenetur, voluptate doloremque officiis dicta quaerat voluptatem rerum natus magni. Eum amet autem dolor ullam.</p>

    <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/500" class="slide-in">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis, deserunt et incidunt eveniet <img src="http://unsplash.it/200/200" class="align-right slide-in"> temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis</p>


    <p>laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex, quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam, quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam, amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>

    <img src="http://unsplash.it/400/400" class="slide-in">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis, deserunt et incidunt eveniet temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex, quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam, quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam, amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio maiores adipisci quibusdam repudiandae dolor vero placeat esse sit! Quibusdam saepe aperiam explicabo placeat optio, consequuntur nihil voluptatibus expedita quia vero perferendis, deserunt et incidunt eveniet temporibus doloremque possimus facilis. Possimus labore, officia dolore! Eaque ratione saepe, alias harum laboriosam deserunt laudantium blanditiis eum explicabo placeat reiciendis labore iste sint. Consectetur expedita dignissimos, non quos distinctio, eos rerum facilis eligendi. Asperiores laudantium, rerum ratione consequatur, culpa consectetur possimus atque ab tempore illum non dolor nesciunt. Neque, rerum. A vel non incidunt, quod doloremque dignissimos necessitatibus aliquid laboriosam architecto at cupiditate commodi expedita in, quae blanditiis. Deserunt labore sequi, repellat laboriosam est, doloremque culpa reiciendis tempore excepturi. Enim nostrum fugit itaque vel corporis ullam sed tenetur ipsa qui rem quam error sint, libero. Laboriosam rem, ratione. Autem blanditiis laborum neque repudiandae quam, cumque, voluptate veritatis itaque, placeat veniam ad nisi. Expedita, laborum reprehenderit ratione soluta velit natus, odit mollitia. Corporis rerum minima fugiat in nostrum. Assumenda natus cupiditate hic quidem ex, quas, amet ipsum esse dolore facilis beatae maxime qui inventore, iste? Maiores dignissimos dolore culpa debitis voluptatem harum, excepturi enim reiciendis, tempora ab ipsam illum aspernatur quasi qui porro saepe iure sunt eligendi tenetur quaerat ducimus quas sequi omnis aperiam suscipit! Molestiae obcaecati officiis quo, ratione eveniet, provident pariatur. Veniam quasi expedita distinctio, itaque molestiae sequi, dolorum nisi repellendus quia facilis iusto dignissimos nam? Tenetur fugit quos autem nihil, perspiciatis expedita enim tempore, alias ab maiores quis necessitatibus distinctio molestias eum, quidem. Delectus impedit quidem laborum, fugit vel neque quo, ipsam, quasi aspernatur quas odio nihil? Veniam amet reiciendis blanditiis quis reprehenderit repudiandae neque, ab ducimus, odit excepturi voluptate saepe ipsam. Voluptatem eum error voluptas porro officiis, amet! Molestias, fugit, ut! Tempore non magnam, amet, facere ducimus accusantium eos veritatis neque.</p>




  </div>

  <script>
   
  
    
      const myImages = document.querySelectorAll('img');

      const myObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
        if (myImages[0].isIntersecting) {
          myImages[0].classList.add('align-left');
        }
        if (myImages[1].isIntersecting) {
          myImages[1].classList.add('align-right') 

          // repeat the above for myImages[2] and myImages[3]
        }
        entries.forEach(e => {
          console.log(e.intersectionRatio)
          if (e.isIntersecting) {
            console.log(e.target)
            e.target.classList.remove('slide-in')
            e.target.classList.add('active')
          }
        
        }),

        { threshold: 0.7,
        rootMargin: "0px 200px 0px -200px"}
      });

      for (var e of myImages) {
        myObserver.observe(e);
      }

  </script>

  <style>
    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: #ffc600;
      font-family: 'helvetica neue';
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    h1 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .site-wrap {
      max-width: 700px;
      margin: 100px auto;
      background: white;
      padding: 40px;
      text-align: justify;
    }

    .align-left {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 20px;
      transition: all 0.5s;

    }

    .align-right {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 20px;
      transition: all 0.5s;

    }

    .slide-in {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.5s;

    }

    .align-left.slide-in {
      transform: translateX(-30%) scale(0.95);
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    
    .align-right.slide-in {
      transform: translateX(30%) scale(0.95);
      transition: all 0.5s;

    }

    .slide-in.active {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }

  </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I don't think the problem coming from intersection observer. If you check in devtools while scrolling your page, images class change from slide-in to active. I don't exactly know what you want to achieve, but at the moment you remove the class with opacity 0, you don't animate it

Comment: look here https://github.com/pierfarrugia/reveal_animate

Comment: Thank you, Pier. I have edited my post to clarify what I am trying to achieve. I still don't understand how I would trigger the CSS transition. After reading your comment, I deleted the ".remove(slide-in)" line in my JS, and I see there is some improvement in how the effect works. However, each image acts differently - some slide in horizontally, others just fade-in without sliding...